# Can not change the background to white in the Canvas animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I found a Canvas animation that fits my site, but I can't remove the background from it (or replace it with white) when replacing the background with a light one, the animation disappears immediately.

I'm just starting to get acquainted with Canvas, so do not swear much.

Here is a normal background (line 162): https://codepen.io/obiwan-kenobi/pen/vQyBxP

```
 drawGradient ({ctx, canvas, bounds}) {
 ctx.fillStyle = '# 252f3d';
 ctx.fillRect (... bounds.params); }
```

But with white (I made it gray so that the animation could be seen, but on white there are none at all, line 162): https://codepen.io/obiwan-kenobi/pen/GwNKYg

```
 drawGradient ({ctx, canvas, bounds}) {
 ctx.fillStyle = '# e2e1e1';
 ctx.fillRect (... bounds.params); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the example you posted uses a particular compositing operation named "screen" that always result in a lighter color. Since there is no lighter color than white all shapes are invisible on a white background.

To solve your specific problem  you may change the value of this property from "screen" to "multiply" and your background to white:

```
// row #162
ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';

/// .....

// row #450:
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/DanieleAlessandra/pen/pQNvpz)

All available values for this property can be found here --> [globalCompositeOperation reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped me out.

Now the very first "wave" is black, although I indicated the colors red, green and blue, but how to set the color of the very first "wave"?

Comment: "multiply" results always in dark colors (like "screen" results always in light colors). Multiply with red, green and blue is aways black. If you want a different final color you have to use three very light tint, try these: `const colors = [
  '#FF0099',
  '#00FF99',
  '#9900FF'
];`

Comment: Here is another article about blend modes to help you understand better this feature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes

Comment: Yes, I already understood it, thanks. source-over helped me to make the color of the wave, which is listed last in the "color" array. Thanks again. Or maybe there is some way to set a specific color for the topmost wave?

I want to make this waves around the entire screen. To make it look like a “border” in CSS.

Comment: An example can be seen on the site www.makemepulse.com/

Comment: To achieve that result i'd use the default blend mode (that is "source-over") and a linear gradient to fill shapes instead of plain colors. You may find useful tutorials on canvas here --> https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/

Comment: I got both a gradient and a frame around the screen. But after I made the background transparent, the animation began to leave traces. You don't know how to fix it? https://codepen.io/obiwan-kenobi/pen/JebWjG